# Sonar Ruby Plugin - Saikuro returns no results

Tags: ruby, sonarqube, sonar-runner, metric-fu

I'm really stuck on this one. I built the Godaddy Ruby plugin for Sonar and it seems to run fine, I can log out results from Cane and others, but at this line:

https://github.com/GoDaddy-Hosting/ruby-sonar-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/godaddy/sonar/ruby/metricfu/MetricfuComplexityYamlParserImpl.java#L38

I get a null pointer exception because Saikuro doesn't seem to be in that object. I'm wondering if I'm missing a configuration item or something. Has anyone seen this problem?

What's more annoying is that if I comment out the offending code, none of the results of the other analysis tools get saved to Sonar. I get a massive MetricFu results.yml but nothing is reported to Sonar.

Answer (score 0):

A quick glance at the code looks like it might rely on the old metric_fu interface...  Your version of metric_fu might be too new for the above code. Please enter an issue on the metric_fu issues tracker and we can help you better, there. https://github.com/metricfu/metric_fu/issues